# When does the inequality $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$ not hold?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I was trying to find the least value of $|\sin x|+ |\cos x|$ and applied the above inequality as :

$|\sin x + \cos x| \le |\sin x| + |\cos x|\\
\Longrightarrow  \sqrt{2} \le |\sin x| + |\cos x|$

But the range of the given function is $[1,\sqrt2]$. Any idea what might have went wrong here?

Comment: Isn't $\sqrt{2}$ the least upper bound of both $|\sin x + \cos x|$ and $|\cos x| + |\sin x|$?

Comment: Your first inequality should be $\leq$. Your second inequality does not follow from the first.

Comment: Why do you think that $\lvert \sin x+\cos x\rvert<\lvert \sin x\rvert+\lvert\cos x\rvert$ implies $\sqrt2<\lvert \sin x\rvert+\lvert\cos x\rvert$ ?

Comment: Could some edit my question to add the less than equal to sign? I can't seem to find it. Add it everywhere you get the less than sign.

Comment: If you use MathJax here (as recommended) type `\le` for $\le$.

Comment: Taking sin x =x and cos x =y and using the above relation |x+y| <(less than or equal to) |x| + |y|

Comment: I made an edit. Are you able to finish the rest? (And check if I did it correctly)

Comment: Here is what you have:$$|\sin x+\cos x|\le|\sin x|+|\cos x|\\|\sin x+\cos x|=|\sqrt2\sin(x+\pi/4)|\le\sqrt2$$Carefully notice the direction of the inequalities and tell me is your conclusion correct?

Comment: @Shubham Johri Umm...yes, I think it is correct. The highest value of |sin x + cos x| is √2 which should be the least value of |sin x| + |cos x|?

Comment: Thank you for the edit

Comment: @McFluff The highest value of $|\sin x + \cos x|$ is $\sqrt{2}$, but that only occurs at specific values of $x$ such as $\pi/4$. It doesn't follow that $\sqrt{2} \leq |\sin x| + |\cos x|$ for *all* values of $x$. For example it's clearly false if $x=0$.

Comment: In $\Bbb{R^1}$, when $x,y$ have the same sign.  In $\Bbb{R^2}$, when the *vectors* $x,y$ have the exact same direction.

Comment: @Bungo Suppose I define y € (0,4) and y $\leq$ x shouldn't that imply x >4?

Comment: @McFluff OK... surely those two conditions would not imply $x > 4$. For example $y=1$ and $x=2$ would satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Oh, I see what a fundamental liitle thing I missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't hold iff $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. As for your problem remember that if $a\leq 1$ then $a^2\leq a$ so $$ |\sin x|+|\cos x|\geq |\sin x|^2+|\cos x|^2=1$$

and for upper bound (remember $(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$): $$|\sin x|+|\cos x| \leq \sqrt{2(|\sin x|^2+|\cos x|^2)}= \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: I couldn't add the less than or equal to sign. Kindly consider that instead of just the lesser than sign.

Comment: To typeset $\leq$, use `\leq`.

Answer (score 1):

$|\sin x + \cos x| \le |\sin x| + |\cos x|$ is correct.
But, for example, if $x=0$ then both sides are $1$; thus we cannot conclude
$\sqrt{2} \le |\sin x| + |\cos x|$.

Comment: That comes from hit and trial. I see that. But I don't understand what is wrong with my reasoning. You obviously proved it wrong with the example, but I wanted to see the flaw in my theory.

Comment: Your $\Longrightarrow$ is just wrong.

Comment: @McFluff your proof is wrong because $|\sin(x)+\cos(x)|$ does not equal the constant function $\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\begin{cases}f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)\\g(x)=|\sin(x)|+|\cos(x)|\end{cases}$

Notice that $g(x+\frac{\pi}2)=|\cos(x)|+|\sin(x)|=g(x)$ so

$g$ is periodic of period $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and we can study it on $[0,\frac{\pi}2]$.

But on this interval both $\sin$ and $\cos$ are positive, so we can get rid of absolute values and $g(x)=f(x)$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}2]$.

You now can use the addition formulas to transform $f$ to $f(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}4)$ and see that $|f(x)|$ has values between $0$ and $\sqrt{2}$ while $g(x)$ has values between $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$.